# Resource file cannot be found

Tags: java, resources, properties

I'm new to Java. I use Eclipse IDE. I have such structure of packages :

```
Java src:
         -1)org.pdfbox;
         -2)org.pdfbox.util;
         -3)org.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.documentnavigation.outline
         - .....
         -4)org.pdfbox.util;
                         -4.1)ResourceLoader.java - loads data from .properties file ;
                         -4.2).....
                         -4.3).....
         -5)org.pdfbox.Resources;
                         -5.1)files to be downloaded (*.properties).
```

Package with Resources has gray icon, others packages have brown icons. ResourceLoader throws an exception "file cannot be found" when I try to load file from org.pdfbox.Resources. Is there way to include package with properties into project or something else? I have tried to set ab absolute or relative paths to my properties file. Would be very greatful for your help.

Comment: Show us the code used to load the properties, and the stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your properties file is called `myfile.properties`, then your code should look like this:-

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("org.pdfbox.Resources.myfile");

// get the string value from key "myvar" from the properties file
String s = rb.getString("myvar");
```